# Is there a way to undo published changes to a project schedule after using "Update Project" feature?

Tags: ms-project

Someone selected the "Update Project" feature in MS Project in the Project tab, status grouping by accident.  Doing so brought all late tasks to a current or completed status.  Issue was not noticed until two days later and many hours of effort have been put in to progress the schedule since then.  Is there any way to identify what changes were made and revert them back?

I have not made any additional changes to the schedule at this point.  I am hoping to identify what changes were made on a specific day and correct them.